# Something wrong about ExecutorService#submit

Tags: java

```
public class CASTest {

private static final int ii = 10;
public static AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
//public static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(ii);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoRunnable dr = new DemoRunnable();
    List<Future<AtomicInteger>> list = new ArrayList<Future<AtomicInteger>>(ii);
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        list.add(es.submit(new Callable<AtomicInteger>() {
            @Override
            public AtomicInteger call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                    ai.incrementAndGet();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return ai;
            }
        }));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            es.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the console print 
[image]

I wanna the console print like this " 1 2 3 4 ... 10 " in order but why it acting like this?

Comment: You just use `AtomicInteger` wrong. Your code increments the AtomicInteger and returns it. Later you ask the AtomicInteger what value it owns.

Comment: @devpuh thank you sir, I just modify the return value to 'ai.incrementAndGet()' and the programme works fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no synchronization, so nothing guarantees that the 5th thread will increment `ai` from 4 to 5.

The only thing you ensure by using the `AtomicInteger` is that after 10 increments, the final value will be 10.

If you want the 10 distinct values of `ai` to be printed (though in arbitrary order), you should use the value returned by `incrementAndGet`.

```
List<Future<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>(ii);
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
    list.add(es.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int res = 0;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                res=ai.incrementAndGet();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }));
}
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

This will output something like:

```
1
2
7
5
10
4
3
6
9
8
```

All the unique values will be printed, but the order will be arbitrary.